# What are these airport forecasts?

Tags: airports

Euronews does airport forecasts with degrees of green, yellow and red that look something like this:

> [image]

> [image]

> [image]

What is this? What does it mean?

Comment: Surely this is a question best directed to Euronews.

Comment: Just a wild guess: green means conditions are good, amber means fair, and red means bad. Additional clues are in the weather depicted - thunderstorm at Tokyo (red), cloudy at Moscow (amber), sunny in Berlin (green). The plane logo in Tokyo also looks as if it is grounded, but soaring away from Berlin. They are on the weather forecast page.

Comment: No, I think it's something independent about traffic levels. Note the white bar under the plane.

Comment: Please give us a URL where we may see the icons on a Euronews webpage.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica try [here](https://www.euronews.com/weather/europe/germany/berlin) and find the **AIRPORT** tab further down.

Comment: Thanks. I see them now, and found no explanation anywhere on the euronews.com website explaining the icons. I upvoted your question.

Comment: Probably they take data from flightaware

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the symbols indicate the risk of delays as the result of weather conditions, as evident from their old graphic style.

> [image: Blockquote]
>   Taken from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hMQLtNfokoQ

Comment: US airport delays are reported as a duration (or two durations, one each for arrivals and departures) based on actual delays.  It could be something like that, though if it is it would be a change from the image presented here.

Comment: It just looks like it is a general “weather delay risk.” But I’m not sure why they care to forecast something that is so uncommon.